# android conver video to bytearray

Tags: java, android, arrays

i try to conver video from sd card in byte array.i wrote code ,but i am doing something wrong.what is a wrong in my code ? i have no idea what i am doing wrong
this is a my source

```
public byte[] readBytes(Uri uri) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);

    }


    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}



upload_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String fileName = "video.mp4";
            String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/" + fileName;

            File file = new File(completePath);
            Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            try {
                byte[] bytes = readBytes(imageUri);
                Log.e("Byte Array is", String.valueOf(bytes));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(bytes), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

i run my app and result is small streang,not byte array

Comment: String.value of returns a string from bytes... Where are you expecting a string?

Comment: no .i returned byterarry to strean with String.valueof

Comment: So whats the issue here then?